# How can I bind checkboxes to an image

Tags: android, image, checkbox

I want to bind checkboxes to a specific place on an image. Here is an image how I would like it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p00NO.png
The red squares are the checkboxes and the black squares are there where I want this checkboxes. The problem is that the position of the checkboxes will change when the screen gonna change. So they will not stay in the black squares. Is there any chance to do this?

Ty in advance.

Comment: can you be more specific, your question is a little unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon" 
    android:text="" android:layout_x="58dip"  
    android:layout_y="106dip"></CheckBox>
```

And if you want to put your checkbox on image at center-bottom then do something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use the above layout for your each view by inflating it and set images according to your need by using relative layout id.

Comment: I tried it but I have more checkboxes than one. The first idea from is just for "LinearLayout" so not useable for my project and the last one is just for one checkbox. Another idea?