# Android: How to draw a rect in a ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, draw, rect

i need to draw a rect in the middle of an ImageView to create a CostumeCheckBox. Im new in Android and i have no idea to do this.
The ImageView/CostumeCheckbox has a Border:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Rect rect = new Rect();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);        
    paint.setColor(CheckboxBorderColor);        
    paint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
    getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint); }
```

Comment: you not need to create custom for this purpose. What exactly you want to do? do you want checkbox on your image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For reference check my answer to slimier question : [How can I bind checkboxes to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589113/how-can-i-bind-checkboxes-to-an-image/18589224#18589224)

Answer (score 0):

In case having the regular checkbox ontop of your imageview is a workable solution for you, you could just put them both inside a FrameLayout. No need to draw the checkbox yourself, you can add it in XML:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageView .../>
    <CheckBox .../>
</FrameLayout>
```

The order of the elements inside the FrameLayout defines the Z-Order, last element is on top. Check out the FrameLayout here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html